# PCB design of the copper area of a (linear) power supply

Tags: pcb, amplifier, pcb-design, analog, pcb-layers

I design an amp with 2 linear power supplies (1 HV main PSU+1 LV preamp PSU) and other devices. My concept is to put the star point onto the board of the main PSU:[image: PSU PCB][image: Star Point]

I have some concerns / questions about my concept:

1. I have a big ground area on the front copper (red area). The area
   between the big reservoir caps has high ripple currents. Does this
   affect my star point negatively or is it far enough? Is it better to
   just draw a thick track from reservoir ground to the star point
   (without big ground area) ?
2. Is it a good idea to put the star point onto the board of the main
   PSU? Or is it better to connect everything including the main PSU
   somewhere externally using thick wires? Will this have better
   immunity from ripple currents?
3. I used relatively big areas as power lines and high current lines (yellow areas, back
   copper) instead of thick tracks because of high current. Good idea?
   Will it cause any issues with capacitance? Should I use more
   decent/thinner power lines?

Answer (score 1):

You have a big area under your capacitors that will certainly have ripple currents so, you have to decide where in that mass of copper is to be your star point. It doesn't too much matter where you decide that to be. It can be along any edge of that copper but. clearly it cannot be inside the copper block.

Once decided upon, stick to that. There will be no ripple currents flowing from that star-point unless you break that single-connection rule. Whatever ripple currents circulate in the big copper area won't circulate on (or from) the star-point connection unless you break the rules.

> Is it a good idea to put the star point onto the board of the main
>   PSU? Or is it better to connect everything including the main PSU
>   somewhere externally using thick wires? Will this have better immunity
>   from ripple currents?

Using the main PCB (as your 2nd picture begins to indicate) should not be a problem. Stick to the star-point rules (just a reminder). You can use wires or you can use PCB tracks. Stick to the rule (there I've said it again).

> I used relatively big areas as power lines and high current lines
>   (yellow areas, back copper) instead of thick tracks because of high
>   current. Good idea? Will it cause any issues with capacitance? Should
>   I use more decent/thinner power lines?

I have no idea what you are saying or asking in (3).

Answer (score 1):

> I have a big ground area on the front copper (red area). The area
>   between the big reservoir caps has high ripple currents. Does this
>   affect my star point negatively or is it far enough? Is it better to
>   just draw a thick track from reservoir ground to the star point
>   (without big ground area) ?

In the place of copper, imagine resistors. The value of this resistance is determined by the cross sectional area of the copper. It gets slightly more complicated than this when you add in effects from AC because copper also has inductance but you get the idea. This is called parasitic resistance and inductance.

It can be modeled, without looking at a schematic of your design, it is impossible to say which way would be better. In general, you want as little resistance as possible when the current returns back to the source or you get a problem with a common mode voltage such as the one shown below

[image]
Source: Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering Henery W Ott

Because you have two currents flowing back through a pin or a ground plane (usually pins are lower resistance) it creates a voltage and bumps the ground of your entire design. The best way to combat this is to make sure you have sufficient grounding and calculate the resistance and the current and make sure the common mode voltage will be acceptable.

> Is it a good idea to put the star point onto the board of the main
>   PSU? Or is it better to connect everything including the main PSU
>   somewhere externally using thick wires? Will this have better immunity
>   from ripple currents?

It really depends on your design, sometimes its better and sometimes its not. I had a sensitive analog section that had problems with a star ground and a voltage bump in the uV range becasue of 1 Amp currents returning through the star ground, in that case, I had to put the analog section on it's own supply (the PSU we had did not have a sufficient ground on the board even though it had a fat terminal and the resitance was in the milliohm range). In general a star ground is better because it further avoids common mode problems.

You are not really protecting anything from the ripple currents of the caps, by moving them further away from your ground those currents have to flow back to the source (which is probably the PSU), and the will take the path of least impedance (Resistance+inductance) to do so. If you really do need to isolate AC, then use inductance, inductance blocks AC.

> I used relatively big areas as power lines and high current lines
>   (yellow areas, back copper) instead of thick tracks because of high
>   current. Good idea? Will it cause any issues with capacitance? Should
>   I use more decent/thinner power lines?

Big areas and large traces decrease inductance and resistance, and generally improve things power-wise because the PCB version of your design looks closer to your schematic. (ie, when you draw a wire between two points on a schematic it has no resistance or inductance, when you draw it on the PCB it does. Good engineers use calculators when necessary to find out if this affect their design by calculating the resistance and inductance of each trace, wire and pin and finding the effects on their design).

Another benefit of making large traces\planes is a small amount of capacitance between planes (usually in the pF range sometimes nF's and can also be calculated). Usually pF's and nF's mean filters in the +100Mhz range.

Another problem of increasing resistance is power loss and heating, if the traces are not thick enough, you can burn them out or cause unnecessary heat in areas on your PCB.

Get this [book to learn more](https://books.google.com/books?id=2-4WJKxzzigC&pg=PA628&dq=when%20a%20trace%20crosses%20a%20split%20plane&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja8P2y7o3SAhXKhVQKHZv1A8EQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=when%20a%20trace%20crosses%20a%20split%20plane&f=false)